# Expected length of Stalin-sorted sequence

Tags: probability, expected-value, sorting

There is a [pogramming meme](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/9s9kgn/nononsense_sorting_algorithm/) called Stalin sort which works as follows: the algorithm proceeds from left to right and each time it encounters a value $a_i$ less than the previous one $a_{i-1}$ the element $a_i$ is removed from the sequence.

Visualization of Stalin sort can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/ekzrb8/stalin_sort_visualized/).

My question is, given a positive integer $n$ what is the expected length of the Stalin-sorted permutation of the sequence $1,...,n$ (we treat all these permutations as equally probable).

I tried to calculate it mathematically but things got messy. Then I wrote [code](https://pastebin.com/GDYmmZFb) to find out the expected length. Here are the first several values:

| n | expeceted resulting sequence length |
| --- | --- |
| $1$ | $1$ |
| $2$ | $1.5$ |
| $3$ | $1.8333333333333333$ |
| $4$ | $2.0833333333333335$ |
| $5$ | $2.283333333333333$ |
| $6$ | $2.45$ |
| $7$ | $2.592857142857143$ |
| $8$ | $2.717857142857143$ |
| $9$ | $2.828968253968254$ |
| $10$ | $2.9289682539682538$ |

Comment: So if you remove $a_i$, then $a_{i+1}>a_i$ you retain $a_{i+1}$ no matter what?

Comment: Looks like the partial sums of the harmonic series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Partial_sums

Comment: With the sequence 3, 1, 2 - would 2 be removed (less that 3) or kept (greater than 1)? I think your description implies removed.

Comment: @user10354138, yeah, correct.

Comment: @preferred_anon indeed, very interesting. Thanks!
Yeah, 2 will be removed too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $n$ and $k\in\left[n\right]$, denote by $R_{k}$ the even that the $k^{\text{th}}$ entry of a permutation $\sigma\colon\left[n\right]\to\left[n\right]$ chosen uniformly at random is retained by this sort. Then it follows from linearity of expectation that the desired expected length is
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{k\in\left[n\right]} \mathbb{1}_{R_{k}}\right)\ &=\ \sum_{k\in\left[n\right]} \mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{1}_{R_{k}}\right)\\
    &=\ \sum_{k\in\left[n\right]} \mathbb{P}\left(R_{k}\right)\\
    &=\ \sum_{k\in\left[n\right]} \frac{\left(k-1\right)!}{k!}\\
    &=\ \sum_{k\in\left[n\right]} \frac{1}{k}\\
    &=\ \log\left(n\right)+\gamma+o\left(1\right)\text{.}
\end{align*}